# Xamarin iOS - Screen Flow

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I have this options of navigation flow in the application around my UIViewControllers

A->B->C

A->D

In C, there is an option allows the user to D. C and D aren't connected to each other by segues but both are from A.

I've tried from C present D and dismissing C but it brings me back to B.
In android, i would normally do two popbackstack and show D. 
How can I do it in Xamarin iOS?

Comment: Does your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `PushViewController` from C to D, you can easily go back to A with `NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);`

If you use `PresentViewController` from C to D, you can present D first and then call `PopToRootViewController` in C.

Here is the code in C:

```
    UIViewControllerD controlD =new UIViewControllerD();

    Action action = () => {
        NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
    };

    myButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {

        //1. navigate to D
        //NavigationController.PushViewController(new UIViewControllerD(), true);

        //2. present D
        NavigationController.PresentViewController(controlD, true, action);
    };
```

code in D when back:

```
    myButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {

        //1. navigate to root ViewControll
        //NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);

        //2. Dismiss D
        this.DismissViewController(true,null);

    };
```

I uploaded my sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/navigation-in-xamarin.ios) and you can check. Feel free to ask me any question.